# EXPO SNACK: Error getting latest hash: Failed to get latest commit hash for repository

Tags: git, expo, repository, git-hash

I am committing my repo to an expo snack and I am receiving the error:

Error getting latest hash: Failed to get latest commit hash for .

Is this because I am not using the proper URL to link to my repo or something else...I am not sure how to commit the latest hash in this case.

[image: Here is the ERROR]